# Is there a way to add methods to a type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

So I am used to languages like Swift and Rust, where you can declare functions on a type or interface after the fact.

I.e. in Rust, I can declare a data type, and then add methods using an `impl` declaration:

```
struct Rectangle {
    width: f64,
    height: f64
}

impl Rectangle {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        self.width * self.height
    }
}
```

And I can do similar in Swift with an extension:

```
struct Rectangle {
    let width: Float
    let height: Float
}

extension Rectangle {
    func area() -> Float {
        return self.width * self.height
    }
}
```

Is there a similar tool available in typescript to add methods to a typescript interface or type?

Comment: Interfaces and `type` declarations don't have method implementations. You need a `class` for that. Are you trying to extend a third party's definition? Or are you just wanting to define data and types (a `class`)?

Comment: The static type system in TypeScript, including all `interface` and `type` definitions, is completely erased when TS is compiled to JS; there's nowhere for such implementations to live.  Furthermore the type system is *structural*, so you'd be suggesting that any object in all of JavaScript which happened to have a `width` and a `height` property of type `number` would automatically get a magic `area` method, which would be a problem if any object had its own `area` property or method.

Comment: You're getting answers where people are adding method *signatures* to interfaces, but you are specifically asking for *implementations*, right?  Please be explicit about it either way.

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to add an implementation to all instances of an interface

Comment: You should [edit] the question to make that explicit.  The answer is going to be “no” though.  If you want an explanation for why TypeScript fundamentally cannot do something like this I can write it up.  If you’re more interested in workarounds then one of the below answers about using classes might be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

In theory its possible. There are many ways to do that. Class is one of them

[playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-m2h4ew)

```js
interface IRectangle {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  area: () => number;
}

class Rectangle implements IRectangle {
  constructor(public readonly width: number, public readonly height: number) {}

  area() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

const rectangle = new Rectangle(4, 4);

console.log(rectangle.area());
```

Comment: Does this count as "adding a method implementation to a type"?  A value of type `IRectangle` is now required to have a number-producing `area` function property, but the implementation can be anything: `const weirdRectangle: IRectangle = {width: 1, height: 1, area: () => 123}`.  I don't see this as answering the question as asked, although the answer to that question is just "no" and this might be a reasonable *workaround*.

Comment: I said, that there's many ways to reach the expected result and thats possible one. If you need the rectangle class not to have the area method, you can make it optional (?) or create class Rectangle without the method and create an ExtendedRectangle that extends Rectangle and has area method. There can be plenty of workarounds to resolve the question,

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript interfaces don't include any runtime implementation code, but you can extend existing interfaces. Here's an example:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQWOIDmAbFAbwFgAoZZACwmB0rAC5kQBXAWwCNoBuMigd2AATMJSatOPMgF8yZUJFiIU6TNnxE+yOFAhwmACgCUyALwA+ChK5RepWaTIIA9iADOYZFCaqsuAmbIJORUNHSMyADMADRagiJiyABMsSE6esjGQVoUumAsUCDIosBuAHTUtPTIAFTFlKVl8aJ2FNKp0nZOrm7OBGV4zjgGUGXpcMZGdkA)

```ts
interface Rectangle {
  height: number;
  width: number;
}

interface Rectangle {
  area: () =>  number;
}

const r: Rectangle = {
  height: 3,
  width: 2,
  area () {
    return this.height * this.width;
  },
};

console.log(r.area()); // 6
```

Or as a class:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCmwAuYB2BzE9oG8CwAUNNABbwCW6JSAXNKgK4C2ARvAE4DchxA7uQBMkJOo1YduBHtGAB7VBCTsGyWe2gAKfkJH1mbdgBpSFKrT3j2ASlzTiw8hAB024dAC80VyUnF7JRycySmoPExCkX2gAX0JpMHZ4ME0rUX0OWyI-RKQGdlRoB2dgs2gAKkKA528o2II6wjkFJGh1T1R4XjhEFAwsDQAmYwBmK0kmiFksJxBZdA12JwSkjSsx6AB6DegANkIgA)

```ts
class Rectangle {
  height: number;
  width: number;

  constructor (width: number, height: number) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }

  area (): number {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

const r = new Rectangle(2, 3);
console.log(r.area()); // 6
```

Comment: you have duplicated interfaces names

Comment: @Gorynych Correct. TypeScript merges them.

Comment: Yep, I know. But why?)

Comment: So if I do this, do I get area for free if I declare a new Rectangle, or do I have to add it to every instance myself?

Comment: @sak No, if you are trying to stay in step with Rust idioms, a class is the best approach. I've updated my answer to show that approach as well. When using a class, there's no need to define an additional interface type unless you need the properties for something else as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on class. Create class with constructor that implements the interface. And inside class find out the area with `area` method. This way you dont have to create area method every time.

See the code below:

```
interface Rectangle {
  height: number;
  width: number;
}

class ChildRectangle implements Rectangle{
  height: number;
  width: number;
  area(){
    return this.width * this.height;
  }
  constructor(height: number, width: number) {  
        this.height = height;  
        this.width = width;  
    }  
}


let childRectangle = new ChildRectangle(5,3);
console.log(childRectangle.area());
```

You can [play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQWOIDmAbFAbwFgAoZZACwmB0rAC5kQBXAWwCNoBuMigd2AATMJSatOPMgF8yZBHjgBnJcgDClYHiHpM2fCmBsADgTYRwq3VlwES5KjTqNm7LlF4PBIsa8ke+ZDgoCDgACgBKewoKELAWKBBkUWAlADpvUWQAKmTNdOpaek8KWQcEAHsQJTAoFkwKqDDC53E3aAAaZEzfCXcI5EIKQJiYlIKnemQAXkcisG5hh1GKcYzhLNmexeQR5GklsrlSAjBkBE1ta30CGeYIfnVLnQwbAzCAVg6AZgjPSuqFQIaTwFRwYQuWheelsEDSwVCkT+QA) here.